# Filtering by object using the special $ character in angularjs is not working

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, filter, dataset

According to angularjs documentation you should be able to pass in an oject to the filter method.  You can specify the column to filter when using the object or you can use "the special $" character and it should search all properties.  The filter works great when I specify a column name to filter, but when I try to use the $ to filter against all columns it does not work.  I'm not sure if I am using it right.  Anyone know how to correct this problem?

```
        var filterObject = { $ : 'Jeff'};
        $scope.myFilteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.myRawData, filterObject);
```

Comment: What's in your myRawData? It has to be an array of objects that have properties that can be filtered on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular filters require an array and a filter object of some type to work. You can find more in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter. By default the $filter('filter') call will return the inbuilt generic/simple filter. Your first argument then needs to be an array of objects with properties. Your second arg can be an object like you've demonstrated.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ExampleCtrl', 
function ($scope, $filter)  {
        var x = [{name : 'Tim'}, {'name'  : 'Jim'}, {'name'  : 'Jeff'}];

        console.log($filter('filter')(x, {$ : 'Jeff'}));
});
```

Find it at http://jsfiddle.net/wg6mp56y/1/

Comment: Turns out this works... there was just problem with the object I was passing my results to.  It is good to see a working example of this though as not a lot of web resources reference the $ based object filtering.

Comment: Sweet glad it works. BTW it's not really idiomatic to use the filter this way but I'm sure you know that..